# Exception during BsonDocument serialization - asp.net core + mongodb

Tags: asp.net, mongodb

i cant seem to figure what im doing wrong during simple c# class serialization to BsonDocument. I have very simple example of asp.net core code that always ends up with same exception: DummyClass cannot be mapped to BsonType.Document.

POCO class:

```
public class DummyClass
{
    [BsonElement]
    public string Name;
}
```

Later i try to serialize the class to BsonDocument like this

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<DummyClass>();
DummyClass model = new DummyClass();
model.Name = "test";
var document = BsonDocument.Create(model);
```

I have tried loads of different setups with/without the attributes but the result is still the same :(

Any ideas what im doing wrong?

Cheers